# Ошибка при возбуждении ошибки в тернарном операторе Python

Tags: python, тернарный-оператор

мой код, имеющий следующий вид возбуждает такую ошибку:

```
class Storage:
    connection: MySQLConnection
    cursor:     MySQLCursor

    def set_values(self, *, data: Dict[str, Any]) -> None:
        self.connection = connect(**data)
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()

    def open_connection(self) -> None:
        raise ValueError("The database settings must be filled in.") if not DATABASE \
            else self.set_values(data=DATABASE)

    def close_connection(self) -> None:
        self.connection.close()
```

```
raise ValueError("The database settings must be filled in.") if not DATABASE \
TypeError: exceptions must derive from BaseException
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, с чем бы это могло быть связано? Когда я вместо тернарного оператора пользуюсь обычным ифом все работает окей.

Comment: тернарный иф только при присваивании стоит использовать

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Упрощу вариант, который воспроизводит вашу ошибку:

```
raise ValueError("Something bad") if False else None
```

Выходит:

```
TypeError: exceptions must derive from BaseException
```

Почему так? А просто потому, что читать надо так:

```
raise (ValueError("Something bad") if False else None)
```

Т.е. в обоих случаях срабатывает `raise`, но когда срабатывает с тем операндом, который в `else`, ему непонятно, как это интерпретировать как `Exception`.

Как заставить питон воспринимать `raise` и его аргумент как единую конструкцию в данном случае - я пока не нашёл и не знаю, возможно ли это. Если брать в круглые скобки `(raise ValueError("Something bad"))`, интерпретатор ругается.

Видимо, поскольку `raise` это оператор, других вариантов нормально управлять его исполнением тут нет, кроме стандартной конструкции `if` в виде также оператора.